# selenium Grid2 parallel test on multi browsers fail occasionally with no obvious reason

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I run grid with 2 nodes on the same Linux VM, sometimes (50%) a test fails due to NoSuchElementException, with no real reason, the Element is there - can see it on runtime,
however I can never catch this failure while debugging.
I'm pretty sure it related to parallel testing.

I use Ubuntu 12.04, with Firefox 18 & google-chrome 23.0.
My webdriver instances are initiated in the test method itself.
My testing.xml specifies parallel=methods and I can see all browsers open at the same time and tests are running together.

Is this a known issue? I intended to run even higher parallelism, but the more nodes I add to the VM and more tests I run in parallel - the bigger the failure rate.

Is there a fix for that ?

Answer (score 0):

i can guess that you are running all your nodes on the same VM display, therefore - it is very likely, that your tests are interfering one another when running in parallel, 2 actions (in test) can be executed simultaneously and only one event will actually be executed (like click).
also this probably consumes high compute resources from your node HW.
it is recommended (by me, from experience) to run one node per browser/platform machine when running in parallel to prevent false negatives. (hub can still be in same machine of a node).
or - in linux only you can run different node sessions on different DISPLAY-Xs, this will still consume compute resources and probably slow down the tests if you use too many.

you can try and read this, maybe it will raise some ideas :
[effective ui testing lab](http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/build-effective-web-ui-testing-lab/)